# Zipping a list of files in python

Tags: python, file, dataframe, zip

I have a list of CSV files that I would like to send by e-mail. But I would like to zip it to send as one folder sort of. Anyone that can provide examples of how can I folder a list of csv files, so, therefore, I can use my function to send as e-mail.

I have consulted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240728/zipping-files-in-python) and tried this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474650/how-to-send-a-zip-file-as-an-attachment-in-python)
Seems also that:

```
df.to_csv('my_file.gz', compression='gzip')
```

Only compress one single file, not all over in a list.

**Any help is highly appreciate**

Comment: Don't make us stare down your current code. What is it doing? Why is it even included in your question?

Comment: @timgeb yes, I had to rewrite it as I am looking for examples of how to do rather than just fix my code or so! Thanks